# saveToCassandra() : IllegalArgumentException: Multiple constructors with the same number of parameters not allowed

Tags: scala, hadoop, cassandra, apache-spark

Что я делаю не так? Здесь выдаёт ошибку при запуске:

> `textfile.saveToCassandra("logs", "logstable")`

Весь код:

```
object App extends java.io.Serializable {

  final val APP_NAME = "SparkBatchTest"

  def main (args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(APP_NAME).setMaster("local[2]")
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.native.port", "9042")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val textfile = sc.textFile("hdfs:////tmp/kafka/test/15-12-10/FlumeDat*")

    textfile.foreach(record => seperateFields(record))
    textfile.saveToCassandra("logs", "logstable") //здесь ругается

  }

  def seperateFields(line: String): Tuple5[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object] = {
    println("Waiting...")
    Thread sleep 3000
    println("Saving...")
    val split = line.split(" ").toArray[Object]
    println(line)
    return (split(0) + " " + split(1), if (line contains "Down") "0" else "1", split(5), split(6), split(4))
  }
}
```

Перед форматированием содержание файла следующее:

```
2015-12-10 12:04:48.299 AMP (amp-management-5-sa)[6953]: Aruba RAP-109 a63253686jypmO68380 Down      System Device  ID: 2490    Top > mariscos puerto vallarta   2-Standard
```

таблица в Cassandra выглядит следующим образом:

```
datetime            | location | logid   | status              | systemid
---------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+----------
 2015-12-23 15:10:01 |        1 | RAP-109 | a73225704jypmO54359 |    Aruba
 2015-12-23 15:55:54 |        0 | RAP-109 | a62710684jypmO66318 |    Aruba
 2015-12-23 15:10:02 |        1 | RAP-109 |  a2222705jypmO69412 |    Aruba
 2015-12-23 15:09:45 |        1 | RAP-109 | a80296226jypmO21003 |    Aruba
 2015-12-23 15:25:29 |        1 | RAP-109 |  a11170884jypmO9634 |    Aruba
 2015-12-23 15:55:53 |        1 | RAP-109 | a18255961jypmO91299 |    Aruba
 2015-12-23 16:17:27 |        1 | RAP-109 | a41956492jypmO85560 |    Aruba
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решено, переписал следующие строки:

```
val textfile = sc.textFile("hdfs:////tmp/kafka/test/15-12-10/FlumeDat*")


val res = sc.parallelize(Seq(seperateFields(textfile.first())))
res.saveToCassandra("logs", "logstable", SomeColumns("datetime","location","logid","status","systemid"))
```

и ещё тут чуть-чуть:

```
def seperateFields(line: String): Tuple5[String, String, String, String, String] = {...
```

и всё заработало!